# making a trail that destroys enemies in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

After searching for a way to do this I found a script from robertbu that should work for detecting collisions, I am trying to make it so that when this system detects a collision with "Virus" by using other.CompareTag like you would with `ontriggerenter(other:collider)`. Here's the neccesary part of the script.

```
function Update() {
    if (Hit() == true){
         if (other.CompareTag("Virus")){
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
             }
        }
}

function Hit() : boolean {
    var i = head;
    var j = (head  - 1);
    if (j < 0) j = arv3.Length - 1;

    while (j != head) {

        if (Physics.Linecast(arv3[i], arv3[j], hit))
            return true;
        i = i - 1; 
        if (i < 0) i = arv3.Length - 1;
        j = j - 1;
        if (j < 0) j = arv3.Length - 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Update() {
    Hit();
 }      

function Hit() : boolean {
    var i = head;
    var j = (head  - 1);
    if (j < 0) j = arv3.Length - 1;

    while (j != head) {

       if (Physics.Linecast(arv3[i], arv3[j], hit) && hit.collider.tag == "Virus") {
          Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
    }
        i = i - 1; 
        if (i < 0) i = arv3.Length - 1;
        j = j - 1;
        if (j < 0) j = arv3.Length - 1;
    }
}
```

it works with this code